# How can I print a message using a lambda in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to print `a()` message using lambda, but I can't do this. 
printed Nothing in console. How can I do it?

```
var quackBehavior: QuackBehavior? = null

fun a(){
    quackBehavior?.let{
        it("I want print this message")
    }
}

fun printMessage(){
    quackBehavior = {
        println(it)
    }
}

fun main() {
    a()
}

typealias QuackBehavior = (String) -> Unit
``
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you don't call `printMessage` function, so `quackBehavior` remains null. If you add `printMessage()` call in `main` function before `a()` call, it will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
quackBehavior?.let {
    it("I want print this message")
}
```

The lambda you passed  to `let` will only be invoked if `quackBehaviour != null`. This is the case because you use the safe call operator `?.` which will only invoke functions on a non-null receiver.

Since you don't call `printMessage`, where you intialize `quackBehaviour` it remains `null`.

So to fix it, invoke your functions like this:

```
fun main() {
    printMessage() 
    a()
}
```

---

**Optional:**

You could simplify your code like this:

```
fun main() {
    var quackBehavior: (String) -> Unit = {
        println(it)
    }

    quackBehavior("I want print this message")
}
```

Comment: I understand and solved this problem! Thank you! :D